# AWS Lambda PowerShell script placing file in Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I've written a PowerShell script for AWS Lambda. In the script, I'm calling a cmdlet that has a parameter called OutFile. This cmdlet call, pulls a file from the Uri location and places it locally. I'd like to place this file in Amazon S3.

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $URI -Headers $Params -OutFile "<bucket name>/<directory name>/<my file name>.txt"
```

I'm having trouble correctly putting in the Amazon S3 Bucket and directory name in the OutFile parameter. Can someone please explain how to correctly input the storage location for this parameter?

Thank you,
Mike

Comment: You can't upload to S3 without AWS credentials (unless your S3 bucket specifically allows anonymous uploads). So, assuming your bucket is not public, you either need to use a credentialed SDK (see AWS .NET SDK, for example) or use an S3 pre-signed URL as the target of the upload (which will also require you to get a pre-signed URL using an AWS SDK or CLI).

Comment: Hi Jarmon. This script is not being run from a PC or a server. This is a lambda function. The lambda function is set to be able to work with S3 through an IAM role. Are you saying I need something else? Thanks.

Comment: An IAM role provides the Lambda function with IAM credentials associated with certain permissions (presumably including being able to write to the target S3 bucket). You can't, however, address an S3 object using a typical file path such as `mybucket/dogs/snoopy.png` so you can't use that as the outfile target. If the PowerShell Invoke-RestMethod/Get supports an outfile that is an HTTPS URL then you may be able to supply an S3 pre-signed URL (that's generated by your Lambda function). If not, you're going to need to use an AWS SDK (or the AWSCLI or AWS Tools for PowerShell) to do the upload.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying that. I appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem. By the way, there are a couple of discussed solutions out there in [JavaScript](https://www.serverless.com/examples/aws-node-fetch-file-and-store-in-s3) and [Python](https://www.theinformationlab.nl/en/2021/04/30/scripting-file-download-and-upload-to-aws-s3-with-python/). I've never seen this attempted using PowerShell. JS and Python are simple, mature Lambda runtimes, and have great benefits long-term for future Lambda programming so may be worth considering.

Comment: Thank you again. I'll give those examples a look.